# Split  only on multiple white spaces C#

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say i have a string:

```
"Joe Doe     is    not    here"
```

I want to split this string only where it is multiple white spaces but keep the Joe Doe as one substring.

So that the result would be:

```
string[] result={"Joe Doe","is","not","Here"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a Regex.Split with @"\s{2,}" as the pattern - which will split wherever there are 2 or more whitespace characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
Regex.Split(input, @"\s{2,}")
```

This regex requires min. 2 spaces.

Comment: Doesn't the return value include the spaces?

Comment: @dtb: no it doesn't. You split on 2 or more spaces. Like if you're splitting on ',', you don't get the ',' either :-)